# Python package how to guard against incompatible third-party library update

Tags: python, dependencies

I think I'm missing something fundamental but I can't find the answer to this so please forgive me if this is a stupid question!

I develop Python packages that are used in my organisation. Colleagues install the packages via pip from an internal GitLab instance. They are advised to create a virtualenv but I cannot control that.

Third-party library dependencies are handled by a setup.cfg file. For example my code requires SQLAlchemy v1.3+ but does not work with the new version 2 so I have this in setup.cfg:

```
install_requires =
    SQLAlchemy>=1.3.22,<2
    [...]
```

This works as intended during installation with pip: it currently installs v1.4.xx of SQLA but not v2.x. So far so good.

***What I don't get*** is how can I ensure that a user doesn't (perhaps accidentally) upgrade SQLAlchemy to v2.x in their venv, thus breaking my code?

The only solution I could find so far is to use importlib to check the version of the library that was actually loaded and throw an exception if it is the incompatible v2.x like this:

```py
from importlib.metadata import version 
sqla_major_version =  int(version('sqlalchemy').split('.')[0])
if sqla_major_version >= 2:
    raise Exception("SQLAlchemy v2 is not compatible")
```

Am I doing something stupid, what am I missing?